# Looking for an adverb (or maybe verb?) to represent someone implying "duh"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

I'm looking for an adverb/verb implying what someone would do/look like if they were asked an incredibly obvious question and didn't want to respond with words, just a gesture.

Comment: You mean like a "shrug"?

Comment: I could "glare", but there are other reasons I would "glare".  Ditto "roll my eyes".  Ditto "facepalm"

Comment: *condescend*...

Comment: Step 1: Get a [cluebat](http://ars.userfriendly.org/cartoons/?id=20030210). Step 2: Apply *cluebat*.

Comment: I like the eye-roll suggestion of @JohnFeltz, also knows as the *Oh, God! Three sixty*